# Check if three integer are unique

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to check if three random integer values are unique from each other, and I ‘am struggling on how to solve this. 
I tried solving this with a if statement, and I am feeling that the solution is closing in, but somehow I cannot get it right at the moment. I am also wondering if there is any better or more effective way to solve this problem than using a if statement.

My code so far:

```
Var a1:int;
Var b2:int;
Var c3:int;

If (a1 != b2 && a1 != c3 && b2 != c3){

}else{

}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:java]?

Comment: why not: !(a == b && b == c)

Comment: That really is the best way. (Of course, you have to actually set them to random numbers first...)

Comment: Add them all into a Set and if the set size is 3, then they're unique, if not there must be at least one duplicate

Comment: @AmirAfghani because then maybe a == c

Comment: @hexfraction: because Java and AS3 are pretty similar in the basics (both being a dialect of ECMA script) and easily translated from one to the other?

Comment: And it's actually a question about Boolean algebra, so it applies to many languages. If you know how it works it is one of the key factors in performance optimization. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if (!(a == b || a == c || b == c))`

Tests the following

- FOR a: `a == b`, `a == c`
- FOR b: `b == c` (we already tested `a == b`)
- FOR c: nothing, we already tested `a == c` and `b == c`

The OR concatenation will cause the if-condition to be cancelled as soon as one of the cases is `true`, which, when run in long loops, provides a performance boost.

If none of the conditions returns `true` the result has no duplicates, therefore the boolean NOT `!`.

Comment: Btw, if it's an if-condition where a `true` case returns a specific value you can do this: `if (a == b || a == c || b == c) return yourDefaultValue;` at the beginning of the function. Saves one NOT `!` operation and you won't need an `else` case.